# Confused about result

Tags: php

I wrote just this line and nothing else in my php test file:

```
<?php
echo $y = 13 +'15%'+'$25' ;
?>
```

and it gives the output:
28.

I didn't understand whats the logic behind this. anyone please describe this in brief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is trying to treat these as numeric. And it can for the first two, dropping the non-numeric `%` character.

For the third part though, it starts with a string character and is ignored completely.

Try this as well:

```
echo 13 + "15%" + "5foobar" + 7;  // 40
```

Comment: That is not actually what is happening. It translates each value from the given data type to numeric. So, it doesn't stop at the %. It just translates '15%' to 15. It does actually look at the '$25' and changes that to zero.

Answer (score 2):

PHP recognizes that each value must be numeric. 13 is numeric. '15%' is automatically changed to a number, which is 15. PHP doesn't understand "percent" and doesn't make it 0.15. '$25' is the literal string $25. If you had typed "$25", it would be the variable value for $25 and it would complain that 25 is not a valid variable name (must begin with a letter or an underscore). So, it cannot be translated to a numeric value. It becomes zero. Your result is 13+15+0.

Answer (score 1):

Php will only recognize the first number in your string. Try this:

```
$res1=1+'2a'+'a15'; //3
$res2=1+'2b'+'3b5';  //5 is ignored.result is 6
```